# How to create a heatmap in R- one row at a time?

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm new to R and am trying to generate a heatmap as part of a pipeline that will later on associate the heatmap with metabolic pathways. 
I have data in an excel file in the following form:

```
         tissue1   tissue2  tissue3  ...  
gene1          5         3        1  
gene2        120       400       70  
gene3          0         3        0  
...
```

My goal is to have some kind of a function or method I can call and it will only generate a heat map for the appropriate row, something like heatmap(gene2). I have roughly 800 rows. I want each heatmap to have an independent scale (indep on the other rows)
Is it possible?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry about the table formatting, wasn't sure how to get it right.. gene1..genei are the first col and tissues1..tissuesj are the cols headers. and the numbers are the values..

Comment: To get the code box right, just make sure to indent each line that's a part of it by at least four spaces. (The button marked `{}` at the top of the editor will indent any currently selected code. See also the `?` button at the editor's upper right, for more guidance on formatting using SO's version of markdown.)

Comment: For your heat map, what are your x and y axes?  I assume the numbers in the row are the "intensity".

Comment: The x and y are the tissues and genes, and the values are indeed the intensity. My goal is to create a heatmap for each gene to see the expression (values) in different tissues.

Comment: if `y` is gene, why are you expecting each row? by that way it becomes a vector rather than matrix, and i don't know whether heatmap is what you wanted there.

Comment: It might sound weird but that is what I'm looking for.. a slice of a heat map - just one row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with artificial data, if this is what you want.

```
x=matrix(abs(rnorm(100))*100,10,10,)
image(as.matrix(x[1,]))
```