# R heatmap.2 One row heatmap with color key

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm new to R and i want to generate a one row heatmap from my data using heatmap.2 as reported in "Widespread dynamic DNA methylation in response to biotic stress", Figure 3C  (Dowen et al., 2012). The following is a link to the article: pnas.org/content/109/32/E2183/1

[image]

My effective data is just a column with values between -1 and 1:

```
   deltaMeth
     -1
     -1
    -0.9
    -0.8
    -0.2
     0.3
     0.6
     0.7
     0.8
      1
```

My goal is to create a heatmap similar to the reported by (Dowen et al., 2012) using my dataset.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least provide a link to what you want?

Comment: The link is http://www.pnas.org/content/109/32/E2183/1 , but i dont think everyone will be allowed to see the contents as it is not an open access journal, i tried to upload an image but it is not possible with my actual reputation, sorry.

Comment: I can't believe you didn't find this question when searching: [how-to-create-a-heatmap-in-r-one-row-at-a-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538876/how-to-create-a-heatmap-in-r-one-row-at-a-time)

Comment: yeah i did find it, but i think that it differs considerably from what i want, also if im right it was done with heatmap and not heatmap.2 R function, so i decided to post the question as i believe is not a duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot a heatmap of a one-column dataset with `image`:

```
library(graphics)
mat <- matrix(c(-1, -1, -.9, -.8, -.2, .3, .6, .7, .8, 1))
image(mat)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like an option as thelatemail pointed before but i was looking for a way to do this ussing heatmap.2 as the autors reported they did in the supplementary information of the said article.

Comment: @methdarkz, this cannot be done with `heatmap.2`, see the source code **"'x' must have at least 2 rows and 2 columns"**. The way the scaling and clustering functions are currently implemented requires `matrix` as an input. One would have to change large portion of the source code to be able to obtain what you want. heatmap.2 relies on `image` function to draw the heatmap, hence the above solution is valid.

Comment: @methdarkz, with regard to the paper, I believe the heatmaps which you showed have more dimensions than one. I suspect, they were scaled and clustered using 3 experimental conditions at one time, which would merit using `heatmap.2`.

Comment: Thanks TWL, as i pointed in my post im new to R , and by new i mean just  weeks after i even installed R, and i think i was a little headstrong in using heatmap.2  guided by the quotations in the paper("Data were displayed in a heatmap using the heatmap.2 R function following one-dimensional hierarchical clustering
(hclustfun = hclust, Rowv=T)"), i was  thinking they were one row heatmaps , i guess the one-dimensional part is what made think it was a one row heatmap. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @methdarkz, no worries and welcome to SO. The **one-dimensional clustering** means that the clustering is run either on rows `Rowv=TRUE` **or** columns `Colv=TRUE`. However, the data is 2-dimensional, with experimental conditions on one axis and samples/measurements on the other. Type `?heatmap.2` in R console, and try reproducing the examples at the bottom of the page to gain more perspective. Also, consider [accepting the above answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), since @josilber provided the correct solution for "one row heatmap".

Comment: I got an error doing it, I have the same data( 1 column with expression values) and I got the error: Error in image.default(mat) : 'z' must be a matrix

Comment: @Paul it sounds like you are passing something other than a matrix -- did you try wrapping what you are passing in `as.matrix`? If you can't figure it out, the best approach would be to ask a new question so the whole community can see it. Make sure to provide a reproducible example (enough details so that other can run the code you provide and see the exact error you are getting).