# Stacked single row heatmaps in R

Tags: r, time-series, heatmap, wavelet

I have 10 matrices where each one represent the eigenvalues of correlation matrices of wavelet coefficients of a number of time series.

I would like to generate a heatmap of my data to see if there are any overlapping significant events across the different scales.

So far I have hacked together the following image using the graphics package as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769166/r-heatmap-2-one-row-heatmap-with-color-key) by @Josliber.

I am still getting to grips with R so excuse the nasty code but it works for me for now. I have yet to mess around with the labels and formatting but it's a quick and dirty representation.

[image: Quick and Dirty]

```
#plotting the eigenvalues for each of the wavelet coefficient scales
w1mat <- matrix(w1eigen[1,])
w2mat <- matrix(w2eigen[1,])
w3mat <- matrix(w3eigen[1,])
w4mat <- matrix(w4eigen[1,])
w5mat <- matrix(w5eigen[1,])
w6mat <- matrix(w6eigen[1,])
w7mat <- matrix(w7eigen[1,])
w8mat <- matrix(w8eigen[1,])
w9mat <- matrix(w9eigen[1,])
w10mat <- matrix(w10eigen[1,])

#plots the eigenvalues for each of the scales 
par(mfrow=c(10,1))
imageW1 <- image(w1mat)
imageW2 <- image(w2mat)
imageW3 <- image(w3mat)
imageW4 <- image(w4mat)
imageW5 <- image(w5mat)
imageW6 <- image(w6mat)
imageW7 <- image(w7mat)
imageW8 <- image(w8mat)
imageW9 <- image(w9mat)
imageW10 <- image(w10mat)
```

As you can see I used the image function in the graphics package to create this and I am sure I can achieve the same in ggplot with greater control.

Ultimately I wish to create a plot similar to the one below where there is a common Y axis and they're sitting right on top of one another with no white space.

What I would like to know is whether using the stacked image function in graphics is the best approach or is there a better way to visualise the data in an alternative package?

[image: The desired output]

Comment: Just use `heatmap`. Try `heatmap(matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=10))` for instance. You can `rbind` your matrices together. The quick and dirty way is: `rbind(matrix(w1eigen[1,]), matrix(w2eigen[1,], matrix[w3eigen[1,], ...)` . `...` is where I got lazy.

Comment: Use `do.call` for that sort of thing.